# Deleting rows from a table when i pass a string

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hello everyone i want to create a procedure that receives a `int` and a `string` with the ID's when they are like this:

`Int` CompeteID = 1

`String` TeamIDs = "1,8,9"

Meaning there are 3 TeamIDs, TeamID = 1, TeamID = 8 and TeamID = 9.

Here is my DBModel: https://i.gyazo.com/7920cca8000436cfe207353aaa7d172f.png

So what i want to do is to Insert on TeamCompete, the SportID and CompeteID when there are no equal SportID and CompeteID.

Like this:

```
TeamCompeteID   TeamID  CompeteID
    1              1       1
    4              8       1
    5              9       1
    6              8       1    <---- Can't do this
```

But i also want to delete from TeamCompete the TeamIDs i dont pass onto the procedure for example:

```
TeamCompeteID   TeamID  CompeteID
    1               1      1
    2               3      1    <---- Delete this
    3               4      1    <---- Delete this
```

But I don't want to delete the TeamCompete's that are on the Event table...
Example:

```
EventID TeamCompeteID
   5         3         <---- Can't delete TeamCompeteID 3
                          -- even though i didn't past it on TeamIDs
```

I hope you understanded my explanation.

Comment: Not enough clear. Add for example 15 rows where we can see all variants in one table. I'm not sure for first and second part (might be row_number() over(partition by TeamId, CompeteId order by TeamCompeteId desc) and third part i didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, passing data in this manner is very much a bad idea.  You should really try to normalise your data and have one value in each field.

If however, you cannot avoid this, I would recommend you use a string splitting function such as [Jeff Moden's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) if you are on a SQL Server version prior to 2016 ([the `string_split` is built into SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx)) which returns a table you can join to from a given string and delimiter.

Using Jeff's function above:

```
select *
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K('1,8,9',',')
```

Results in:

```
+------------+------+
| ItemNumber | Item |
+------------+------+
|          1 |    1 |
|          2 |    8 |
|          3 |    9 |
+------------+------+
```

So to use with your table:

```
declare @t table(CompeteID int,TeamID nvarchar(10));
insert into @t values(1,'1,8,9');

select t.CompeteID
        ,s.Item
from @t t
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.TeamID,',') s
```

Results in:

```
+-----------+------+
| CompeteID | Item |
+-----------+------+
|         1 |    1 |
|         1 |    8 |
|         1 |    9 |
+-----------+------+
```

You can then use this table in the rest of your `update`/`insert`/`delete` logic.

Comment: Sorry but can you make a model of the procedure i need to do ? Because i don't understand that much t-sql logic, i'm sorry.

Comment: @Pedro  If you would like to inquire about my consulting rates, then yes by all means.  If you think this website is a free code writing service, then no.  You have everything you need in my answer to start Googling and work the answer out by yourself.